# Will Apple review team approved the app if Sign In with Apple is not implemented for iOS version 12 or earlier?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

Will Apple review team accept the app for publish if Sign in with Apple only implemented for iOS version 13 or later, and earlier then iOS version 13 doesn't have Sign in with Apple option in the app ?

Comment: No they will not reject your application with this issue. hope you have other sigin methods in older os versions.

Comment: @vishnuanilkumar Yes I have other option thats why i am little bit confused that they will accept it or not.

Comment: Then no problem they will accept it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I`m curious, did they accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Apple Sign In the [guideline](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/). Apple has no mandatory iOS version to apply Apple Sign In, and you have to implement it if you have the third party that allows users can register/login like Facebook, Google, or Twitter.